# Applying policy on subscribers to an IObserver - what to return for Subscribe() when subscriber is unwanted?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

Consider an `IObservable<T>` with the following `Subscribe` implementation:

```
public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
{
    if (observer == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("observer");
    }

    lock (_subscriberSync)
    {
        var accepted = OnSubscribing(observer);   // <------ policy can be applied here

        if (!accepted)
        {
            /* #1 */ return null;
            /* #2 */ // return NullSubscription.Instance;
            /* #3 */ // throw new SubscriptionRejectedException("reason");
        }

        // ... perform actual subscription went here
    }
}
```

There doesn't appear to be any guidance as how to establish a rejected subscription. Ideally, we'd have a `Boolean TrySubscribe(IObserver<T> observer, out IDisposable subscription)` or `Maybe<IDisposable> Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)` to represent the conditional, but it seems we only have the option of a flag value or an out-of-band exception. Each has downsides:

With **#1** it seems that all code I've encountered doesn't check for null, and even Resharper static analysis puts a `NotNull` attribute on it.

With **#2** I'd have to test for a `NullSubscription` which isn't much different than #1 except it isn't very discoverable (typical with "magic" return values).

With **#3** we have the typical flow for exceptional circumstances but for deferred subscription it complicates debugging.

Is there any other alternative than these three methods which you've seen implemented?

Comment: You may want to check out the Rxx SandboxedService and MaliciousClient examples here: http://rxx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/71357#1153404. Here's Dave Sexton's blog post on TCP IQbservable security that describes what he did - http://davesexton.com/blog/post/TCP-Qbservable-Provider-Security.aspx.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with `observer.onError(new SomeException())`?

Also, it looks like you're manually implementing `IObservable<T>`, which is [recommended against](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/18_UsageGuidelines.html#UsageGuidelines). If you have to though, you could do this:

```
    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        lock (_subscriberSync)
        {
            var accepted = OnSubscribing(observer);   // <------ policy can be applied here

            if (!accepted)
            {
                observer.OnError(new SubscriptionRejectedException("reason"));
                return Disposable.Empty;
            }

            // ... perform actual subscription went here
        }
    }
```

Comment: OnError is interesting but I see two problems with it: the implicit contract is that it presupposes a subscription and also it leaves me with returning something. As to the guidance, it's just that: guidance. I don't find the Observable factory method suitable in this case, and I understand and have controlled for all the pitfalls.

Comment: What do you mean by presupposing a subscription? It would establish a subscription, just one that immediately yields an error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've got a good reason for implementing `IObservable<T>`, so we'll glaze over that - so if I read your question correctly, you want to know what to return in the case of a "failed subscription" that blends in nicely with the rest of the chained Rx query logic...Hmm...well, I would probably use the `Disposable.Create` method:

```
public class MyObservable<T> : IObservable<T>
{
    private static object _subscriberSync = new object();
    private IObservable<T> _source;

    public MyObservable(IObservable<T> source)
    {
        _source = source;
    }

    protected virtual bool OnSubscribing(IObserver<T> obs)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void DohSubscriptionFailed()
    {
        // Whatever the heck you want to do here?
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, you never got a subscription");
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        if (observer == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("observer");
        }

        lock (_subscriberSync)
        {
            var accepted = OnSubscribing(observer);   // <------ policy can be applied here

            if (!accepted)
            {
                return Disposable.Create(() => DohSubscriptionFailed());
            }

            // ... perform actual subscription went here
            return _source.Subscribe(observer);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage and output:

```
void Main()
{
    // A faked up source
    var source = new Subject<bool>();

    var query = new MyObservable<bool>(source);
    using(query.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine))
    {
        // nothing on output...
        source.OnNext(true);
        // still nothing on output...
        source.OnNext(false);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    // dispose fires, outputs "Sorry, you never got a subscription"
}
```

Now, as written here, the `DohSubscriptionFailed` doesn't do much of anything useful, but depending on your whole use case, you could trigger whatever the heck you want in there.

Comment: I guess codekaizen intention is to let the client know asap if the subscription has been rejected, not only if he actually bother to dispose the returned object.